# Is firing up an AJAX call on page load a bad practice?

Tags: ajax

I use javascript for everything front-end and a PHP that solely serves has a RESTful API.

Is firing up an AJAX call right when the page loads to get the data from the API a bad practice ? Should I send the initial data from the PHP backend first and only then use javascript for eventual modifications ?

Comment: It totally depends on your application. If well done, this can be the right solution.

Comment: It would impact on page load performance (especially if the request is heavy).  You should send down the content directly and only post/get from the server when required.

Comment: Absolutely a bad practice. Prepare the whole html before sending. It's very annoying when a page loads then an ajax spinner starts to load another data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't bad practice. Most pages today include one or more scripts and those scripts are yet sequentially loaded.

So, assuming your content providing backend is fast enough, this would only add one more requests to the existing ones. And if you launch this ajax call immediately when the DOM is ready (i.e. not waiting for all resources to be loaded), the content might very well be available before the images are loaded.

That's why it's more and more common practice, in Ajax applications, to only send initially the application and let it fetch its data after that.